# multiple commands in spawn script to copy keys

Tags: expect

I'm trying to create a script to copy ssh keys to multiple servers for passwordless login. I have a list of servers entered one per line in serverlist.txt. Below is the script I created.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set f [open "serverlist.txt"]
set hosts [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

foreach host $hosts {
spawn -noecho sh -c "cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $host 'mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'"
expect "assword:";
send "abc123\r";  # sending the password
expect "$";       #expecting the $prompt
send "exit\r";
interact
}
```

Im getting below error while running this script

```
send: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"send "exit\r""
    ("foreach" body line 6)
    invoked from within
"foreach host $hosts {
spawn -noecho sh -c "cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $host 'mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authori..."
    (file "sshkeys" line 6)
```

If i commented below lines I'm getting diff error

```
    #expect "assword:";
    #send "abc123\r";  
    #expect "$";       
    #send "exit\r";

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
user@1.1.1.1's password:
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
ssh: mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys: Name or service not known
```

Note:
ssh-copy-id is not available.
None of the target servers have the .ssh directory created.

Can somebody help me to identify the issue.

Comment: hmm. Try `ssh -tt` to *really* force the tty.

Comment: @glennjackman I had tried -t -t option before. Now I tried ssh -tt with those last 4 lines commented and getting this error.
user@1.1.1.1's password:
tcgetattr: Invalid argument
If those lines are not commented I'm getting the same error(tcgetattr) and password prompt is also not coming.